# Check Table Value exists without Javascript, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, mysqli

Is it possible to check if username and email exists in a database using procedural MySQL without using JavaScript?

Comment: How will the server know what you want to do, if you don't contact it via JavaScript _(**`AJAX`**)_ first?

Comment: Your question can be a bit more clear. For e.g. I don't see the necessity of JS at all, to do what what you want

Comment: What is form posting?

Comment: I am creating a registration page and want to make sure users don't register the same username and/or email. And I don't know a lot about Javascript to begin with that's why I don't wnat to use it to check for duplicity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

This is all that can be answered to your vague and too broad question.

Javascript is totally irrelevant to whatever database stuff. An is not required for the server interaction, you can do anything without it. Just learn basic HTML and PHP. Send a form to server, do whatever you want in PHP, then send the response to the browser.